# integrate flow checking into react-slingshot

Tags: npm, flowtype, react-slingshot

I have a project based on https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot

I want to integrate [flow](http://flowtype.org) into the npm start script so that upon running the start script it starts the flow server, by running `flow` command, and then runs the `flow` command on every *.js file change.

These are the scripts from package.json:

```
"prestart": "npm run remove-dist",
"start": "parallelshell \"npm run test:watch\" \"npm run open:src\"",
"open:src": "node tools/srcServer.js",
"open:dist": "node tools/distServer.js",
"lint": "eslint src",
"lint:watch": "watch 'npm run lint' src",
"clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
"remove-dist": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist",
"build:html": "node tools/buildHtml.js",
"prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run build:html",
"build": "npm run test && node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter progress --compilers js:babel/register --recursive \"./src/**/*.spec.js\"",
"test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
```

I have flow working independently.  I can't figure out how to have the flow command run by the file watcher.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`watch 'flow check' src`

`Usage: watch <command> [...directory] [OPTIONS]`

Read the docs [here](https://github.com/mikeal/watch#cli)